# LINQ return type/value is not what im awaiting

Tags: c#, regex, linq

When i execuse these lines

```
drpdf["meno"] = matches.Cast<Match>().Where(c => c.Groups["ID"].Value == i.ToString()).Select(c => c.Groups["meno"].Value);
drpdf["info"] = matches.Cast<Match>().Where(c => c.Groups["ID"].Value == i.ToString()).Select(c => Regex.Replace(c.Groups["zvysok"].Value, @"^,\s?", string.Empty));
```

it wont save into DataRow value that i want, instead of

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match,System.String]
```

Can you help me pls how to select/cast return value to the readable type? Thanks anyway. Ondro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ queries use `Select`, so you get an `IEnumerable<T>` back. If you want the result of your LINQ query, and are expecting exactly one result, add `.Single()`:

```
drpdf["meno"] = matches.Cast<Match>()
                       .Where(c => c.Groups["ID"].Value == i.ToString())
                       .Select(c => c.Groups["meno"].Value)
                       .Single();
```

On the other hand, if your query can have multiple results, you should use `.First()` instead to take the first result. At that point, however, it depends what your scenario is and what you're trying to capture.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
matches.Cast<Match>()
       .Where(c => c.Groups["ID"].Value == i.ToString())
       .Select(c => c.Groups["meno"].Value)
       .FirstOrDefault();  // this expression will evaluate the linq 
                           // expression, so you get the string you want
```

Please note: You should only use FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault if null is actually a valid value in your context. (like said by  @Daniel Hilgarth).

If `null` is not a valid result and instead you want an empty string, append a `?? String.Empty` to the expression:

```
matches
  ...
  .FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: Please note: You should only use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` if `null` is actually a valid value in your context.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your queries are enumerable objects.  Calling `ToString()` on these doesn't give you a meaningful string representation as you have already noticed.  You need to generate a string appropriate for display.

If you simply want to display the contents as a comma-separated list, you can use [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) to do this:

```
var menos = matches.Cast<Match>()
                   .Where(c => c.Groups["ID"].Value == i.ToString())
                   .Select(c => c.Groups["meno"].Value);
drpdf["meno"] = String.Join(", ", menos);
```

Otherwise if you intended to select a single result, use `Single()` to select that single string result.